# how to use Httppost.setEntity in kotlin language?

Tags: android, database, android-studio, http, entity

it gives error on entity
ERROR: expression 'entity' of type 'HttpEntity!' cannot be invoked as a function

[image]
[its me code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMGzE.png)

```
 try {
        
        val httpclient:HttpClient=DefaultHttpClient();
         
        val httppost: HttpPost =HttpPost(URL);

        httppost.entity(UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

         val httpresponse:HttpResponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);

         val httpentity: HttpEntity =httpresponse.entity();

     }
```

Comment: do you mean `httpResponse.getEntity();`

Comment: both httpResponse.getEntity();

Comment: and httppost.setEntity();

Comment: kotlin languge dont use 'set' word it only uses .entity for both set and get

Answer (score 0):

Both entity's getter and setter can be used as a property directly in Kotlin

```
try {

     val httpclient:HttpClient=DefaultHttpClient()
     val httppost: HttpPost =HttpPost(URL)
     httppost.entity = UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)
     val httpresponse:HttpResponse=httpclient.execute(httppost)
     val httpentity: HttpEntity =httpresponse.entity

 }
```